# In Jquery-Validate, how to refer to the name of an attribute in label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'd like to use the label text as the validation message. In order to do this, I tried to use `$(label[for="nameAttrName"])`, snippet here:

```js
$("#myForm").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in " + $(`label[for="NameQuery"]`).text()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>


<form id="myForm">
  <label for="NameQuery">Name Query </label>
  <input name="NameQuery"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Question is, how can I refer to the attribute name in the `for=""` bit so I don't have to write `for="NameQuery"` explicitly? Like this

[image]

Comment: Question makes no sense because every single field under `messages` needs to be listed explicitly anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question is, how can I refer to the attribute name in the `for=""` bit so I don't have to write `for="NameQuery"` explicitly?

Not sure why you would ever need to write this generically since you must list each and every field explicitly within the `rules` and `messages` objects anyway.

However, you could generically target the previous `label` element relative to the field being validated...

```
"Please fill in " + $(element).prev('label').text();
```

And it must be returned from within a `function()` in order to obtain the `element` argument from the plugin...

```
....
required: function(params, element) {
    return "Please fill in " + $(element).prev('label').text();
}
....
```

DEMO:

```js
$("#myForm").validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: {
       required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: {
        required: function(params, element) {
            return "Please fill in " + $(element).prev('label').text();
        }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>


<form id="myForm">
  <label for="NameQuery">Name Query </label>
  <input type="text" name="NameQuery" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This does the job, thanks. However, it is not targeting the exact label. What if there is another label being inserted between the `input` and the NameQuery `label`? Then the answer would target this new label rather than the NameQuery label.

Comment: @thinkvantagedu - apparently you have a DOM structure that’s completely different than what you’ve shown us.   We can’t read minds or see extra code you fail to disclose.  Regardless, my answer shows you how it’s done.  Now it’s up to you to simply adjust the jQuery DOM traversal technique to target the correct `label` element.